# Forward declaration of a class into another in C++ and the benefits

Tags: c++, class, forward-declaration

We have the class `Iterator` forward declared in `Mylist`. `Mylist`'s member functions can use it (as a `return` type for example):

```
template<class Elem>
class Mylist {

public:
    class Iterator;

    ...

    Iterator begin() const;  // iterator to the first element
    Iterator end() const;  // iterator to one beyond the last element

    Iterator insert(Iterator p, const Elem& v);  // insert v into the list after p

private:
...
    class Link;

protected:
    Link* first;
    Link* last;
};

//*****************************************

template<class Elem>
class Mylist<Elem>::Link {

public:
    Link(Elem v, Link* p = nullptr, Link* s = nullptr) : 
        val(v), prev(p), succ(s) { }

    Link* prev = nullptr;
    Link* succ = nullptr;
    Elem val;
};

//****************************************

template<class Elem>
class Mylist<Elem>::Iterator {

private:
  Link* curr;    

public:
    Iterator(Link* p) : curr(p) {  }

    Iterator& operator++() { curr = curr->succ; return *this; } // forward
    Iterator& operator--() { curr = curr->prev; return *this; } // backward

    Elem& operator*() { return curr->val; } // get value (dereference)

    bool operator==(const Iterator& b) const { return curr == b.curr; }
    bool operator!=(const Iterator& b) const { return curr != b.curr; }
};
```

but can an object of class `Iterator` (*p*) also use any of the member functions or stuff of the class `Mylist`, where it has been forward declared?
If so, how?

Comment: At the line where you use `Iterator p`, the class `Iterator` is not yet defined. You can't use `p` at all. I am not sure what you are hoping to do with `p` at that point.

Comment: I'm going to make a specific (non-complete) *list* and use the function *Iterator insert*. What *line* did you mean at the beginning of your comment, please?

Comment: `Iterator insert(Iterator p, const Elem& v);`